# active class not working on index page when index doesn't have in url

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

myapp
├── index.php
├── apps.php
├── contact.php
└── sidebar.php

in **sidebar.php**

```
<nav class="side-bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php" class="category" >
                    <i class="fi fi-bs-home"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="room.php" class="category">
                    <i class="fi fi-bs-apps"></i>
                    <span>Room</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contact.php" class="category">
                    <i class="fi fi-br-comment-alt"></i>
                    <span>Contact</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

in **index.php apps.php contact.php**

```
#more code here
 <php include('sidebar.php');
 #more code here
```

and I use some of JavaScript to add active class on the link of my current page

**Note** I use active class to highlight on the link of my current page

```
const category = document.querySelectorAll('.category');
const activePage =windows.location.href;
category.forEach(link =>{
    if(link.href === activePage){
        link.classList.add('active');
    }
})
```

**Problem**

Active class work normally when I link to any page like `..\myapp\index.php` , **But when i open `..\myapp\` It will auto open `index.php` that make my link tag `index.php` page doesn't have active class**

**What I want?**

I want to make it active class on home Page (index.php) when I open `../myapp/` in the url

Comment: The problem is you're comparing a literally href against a document url when the page is the index.php it is not equal to the href '/' so.. try catching that by using a conditional like an if

Comment: Using `index.php` as the “default” script in a folder is very a common practice, but by no means a standard, and JavaScript is thus unaware of it. It could be “default.asp”, “index.html”, or literally anything. So you need to tell JS about your unique one-off situation for a specific URL. Also, use either `/` or `/index.php`, don’t mix and match, just pick one, you’ll be happier in the future.

Comment: Add a unique id to each item and use the **id** instead of the **href** for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's that what you want, but I did something on my own project.

```
<?php
$filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$filename = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);
?>

<div class="top-nav">
    
    <?php if($filename == 'CopyMail'){ ?>
    <a class="active top-item home" href="#home">Acceuil</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a class="top-item home" href="../reusable/pages/index.html">Acceuil</a>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if($filename == 'write'){ ?>
    <a class="active top-item write" href="#write">Écrire</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a class="top-item write" href="pages/write.php">Écrire</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I will explain my code (I know this is note the best but it work)

the two first line get the current file you on (without the extension) and store it in a variable.

the 'if' statement compare if the current file your on (the previous you've checked) is in this code 'CopyMail', if yes it apply the class 'active' and do some other thing that you might understand. you can add as many as you want and even compare with multiple file name like: `<?php if($filename == 'account' || $filename == 'register' || $filename == 'login' || $filename == 'creation') ?>`

Hope this helped